# Combine results into array in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I got the following `postgresql` tables:

```
Table "public.dates"
Column          |         Type            
----------------+-------------------------
id              | integer                       
start           | timestamp with time zone      
end             | timestamp with time zone     



Table "public.date_participants"
Column   |  Type           
---------+--------
date_id  | integer                  
user_id  | integer
```

I want to get a date with all its participants as an array. For example:

```
{ id: 252, start: xyz, end yzx, participants: [23, 51, 63, 67] }
```

So I created the following query:

```
SELECT
  dates.id,
  json_build_array(participants) as participants
FROM
  dates,
  (SELECT date_id, user_id FROM date_participants) as participants
WHERE dates.id=participants.date_id AND dates.ground_event_id = 252;
```

But this results in:

```
id  |          participants           
----+--------------------------------
252 | [{"date_id":252,"user_id":2}]
252 | [{"date_id":252,"user_id":191}]
252 | [{"date_id":252,"user_id":581}]
252 | [{"date_id":252,"user_id":582}]
(4 rows)
```

**How to combine these rows into one row with all its user_ids as participants?**

Comment: 1. please show us the sample data. Only the result is not really helpful. 2. It seems that you want to create a JSON object with a JSON array. Not a simple array. Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_agg(user_id)` as part of your select statement to aggregate all your participant in one array.
As this is the aggregation and the result has to be produced in one row you need to utilize the `group by` as well in your query

*Something like :*

```
SELECT
  d.id,d.start,d.end,
  array_agg(dp.user_id) as participants
FROM
  dates d, date_participants dp      
WHERE d.id=dp.date_id AND d.ground_event_id = 252
group by d.id,d.start,d.end;
```

Comment: . . Why are you converting the value to text?  And have you heard of `JOIN`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for feedback. Actually it does not needed. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do such:

```
select
    dates.id,
    dates.start,
    dates.end,
    json_build_array(
        select user_id from date_participants where date_id = dates.id
    ) as participants
from
    dates
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a working query with help of aggregate:

```
SELECT
  dates.id,
  dates.start,
  dates.end,
  array_agg(date_participants.user_id) as participants 
FROM
  dates,
  date_participants
WHERE dates.id = date_participants.date_id AND dates.ground_event_id = 252
GROUP BY dates.id;
```